# Intellij Idea can't find jar file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import, libraries

I've been trying to import Apache Commons Math into a Scala program in IntelliJ IDEA. I've identified the jar in the file system via project structure dialog. Using the 'jar -tf ' command on the jar file, I see the classes are all there. In the Scala source code I have 'import org.apache.commons.math3._' and yet somehow IntelliJ cannot find the library. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a pom project, you can create a new directory called libs in the project, put commons-math3-3.6.1.jar in the libs directory, select libs, right-click and select Add as Library, you can use it in the project To it.